# Multiple Inheritance and calling methods from different parents with the same name

Tags: python

I am trying to understand how Python multiple inheritance work, especially on the MRO side.

Looking at the example below.

```
class ParentOne:
    def __init__(self):
        self.one = 1

    def echo(self):
        print('this is ParentOne class')
        self.one += 1

class ParentTwo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.two = 2

    def echo(self):
        print('this is ParentTwo class')
        self.two += 2


class Child(ParentOne, ParentTwo):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Child, self).__init__()
        self.x = 1

    def run(self, x):
        self.x = x
        if self.x == 1:
            ParentOne.echo(self)
        else:
            ParentTwo.echo(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = Child()
    c.run(2)
```

I can get the 'this is ParentTwo class' output, but is it appropriate to use ParentOne(self) and ParentTwo(self) in this way? or any other way to call the different parent class methods with the same name?

edit: just tried, if there is some variables that is not usable in child class, passing self will cause error.

> AttributeError: 'Child' object has no attribute 'two'

So is there any method to call the same method name in different parent class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call superclass methods by using:

```
super().echo()
```

Note that in the past this was more explicit and this format can still be used. Since it also allows to 'skip' a parent's method by calling his parent class.

```
super(Child, self).echo() # call echo of superclass of Child, depending on MRO
super(ParentTwo, self).echo() # would call echo on whatever class ParentTwo inherited from but not call ParentTwo.echo
```

But, which one of the two is called depends on the *order* of inheritance, since that defines the MRO (Method resolution order). So the first superclass method is called first.
Instead of copy/pasting, I'll just forward you to a site that explains it really well in my opinion; [Realpython.com](https://realpython.com/python-super/#method-resolution-order)

But I think that deciding for yourself which super class method you want to call will make for unclear coding. And readable code is a very big pro.

Comment: so there is no way to let the child class to choose which echo() to call? super().echo() will call whichever parent that is on the right first.

Comment: The only way I can think of is to declare an instance of the parent class as part of the variables in the child class, then you may choose whichever echo() to be called, but that will forfeit the purpose of inheritance.

Comment: It calls the echo of the first listed parent class, so `ParentOne` echo is called. Think it's good to realize that the order is important. I don't know of many usecases where you'd want to call different methods of a different superclass. You can chain super classes and call all the echo by calling `super().echo()` in each one. But besides that, there's not much you can do except what you posted.